# Can I ship the VSTO run time with my Outlook plugin?

Tags: .net, plugins, outlook, vsto, office-2010

There are certain installation scenarios where the Visual Studio Tools for Office run time will not be present on the end user's machine. This article talks about those installation scenarios among other things:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee712596.aspx

We are targeting Office 2010 and Office 2013 with our plugin, and as mentioned in the article, machines that have Office 2010 can end up not having the VSTO run time (depending on the .NET framework present and what Windows Updates have been installed).

My questions are

1. Can I make this work by shipping the appropriate VSTO run time dlls with my plugin?
2. If (1) is not possible, can I install the VSTO run time without admin privileges, as a part of our plugin's (msi) installation.

Answer (score 0):

1.) Yes, just add the VSTO prerequisite to your setup program.
2.) When your users execute the setup.exe program, if it detects that VSTO 2010 is not present, then it will prompt for admin credentials to install it.

Basically, it comes down to whether you're using ClickOnce or a Visual Studio Setup and Deployment Project to install your addin.  ClickOnce is a binary that a user can run without admin rights and it will install the addin.  Visual Studio Setup and Deployment projects (available in Visual Studio 2010, and a free downloadable extension for Visual Studio 2013, for VS 2012 you need to use the Installshield Limited Edition) produce an .MSI binary.  If you include a setup.exe with your ClickOnce or MSI, then make sure to do the install by running the setup.exe and not the ClickOnce or .MSI so that setup can check for the VSTO prerequisite and install if necessary.

See the following article for a very good overview of installing OFfice addins:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/1666d2b0-a4d0-41e8-ad86-5eab3542de1e/deploying-office-solutions-to-end-user-computers?forum=vsto

Comment: FYI... in Visual Studio when you right-click on your addin project->Properties->Publish Tab then you're using ClickOnce.  To create an .MSI, then you need to add a Visual Studio Setup and Deployment project to your Visual Studio Solution.

Comment: We have already created a fully functional msi that doesn't require admin rights using WIX. However we were running into the scenario where some users might not have the VSTO run time installed on their machines and I was wondering if there was a way to circumvent the requirement for admin privileges to install it (or use dlls directly). If I understand your answer correctly, there is no way to get the VSTO run time on those users' machines without admin privileges. Correct?

Comment: Correct.  http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/e98691fb-4d79-4089-9eeb-d9bca258ce6a/install-vsto-runtime-without-admin-privilidge?forum=vsto

Comment: I'm sorry but if that was what you intended to say, it did not come across clearly in your answer. If you don't mind editing your answer and clearly answering (1) and (2) as presented in my question, I would be happy to mark your answer as accepted.